# Datagrid to ObservableCollection Binding Doesn't Update grid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, grid, observablecollection

Please help me, I have no idea whats wrong. No matter what I try, the grid is just not updated (stays empty).

I want the grid to be bound to an ObservableCollection, but not to genrate automatic cloumns, but to choose two Properties from the object called Product, which is the type this Collection holds.

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid  x:Name="itemsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Product.Amount}" Header="AMOUTN" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Product.Name}" Header="NAME"  />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid >
```

CODE:

```
  public partial class Orders : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

      ObservableCollection<Product> _ordersList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private ObservableCollection<Product> OrdersList
    {
        get { return this._ordersList; }

        set { _ordersList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("OrdersList"); }
    }

    private void addProduct(Product p)
    {
        OrdersList.Add(p);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("OrdersList");
    }
    private void removeProduct(Product p)
    {
        OrdersList.Remove(p);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("OrdersList");
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply need to remove the word `Product.` from your bindings. The `DataContext` of each `DataGridRow` is an object of type `Product`, so your binding should point to the properties on `Product`

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount}" Header="AMOUNT" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="NAME"  />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: @meyou Try adding `ItemsGrid.DataContext = this;` to the constructor of your Window. It sounds like there's no `DataContext` set. You could also use a `RelativeSource` binding on the `ItemsSource` instead: `ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"` to tell the binding where to get the collection from. Oh, and make the `OrdersList` property public

Comment: Thanks, I solved it. Why does it work only if the property public? please explain it to me

Comment: @meyou A public property is required for binding purposes. The binding system cannot access private properties or fields. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes): `The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected, private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base implementation`

Comment: Why would one want to put the entire code-behind of per example a MainWindow in the DataContext in `DataContext = this`? It just doesn't feel right, I would rather set the `DataContext` to the Collection and just set the ItemsSource as `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` Could you please explain why you advice it?

Comment: @Silvermind Typically I would recommend the MVVM design pattern, which means the `DataContext` is a `ViewModel` object, and is not related to the code-behind at all. It doesn't look like the person posting this question was using the MVVM design pattern since the collection was a property of his `Window` object, so the simplest solution was to set the `Window` object as the `DataContext`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `this.DataContext = this;` somewhere. This is best done in the window's `Load` event.

Comment: How about `itemsGrid.ItemsSource = this._ordersList`?